# npgsql treats value as column name

Tags: npgsql

I am passing a value from a DataTable(it's source of course is a Postgres table) to a query and it's treating the value as a column name not a value. I know that it's because of the double quotes instead of single ones but what can I do to fix it?

A query fills a DataTable > I get the string from it's column "name" from it > I pass the string to this:

```
 NpgsqlCommand id_test1 = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT id_test FROM test WHERE name=" + test_name_string, conn);
```

but since it passes the name with " " insetad of ' ', I get an
 ERROR: 42703: column "imaginaryname" does not exist

Comment: The first step for this kind of problems is always to print the generated SQL statement. That usually shows you where the error is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because `name` is a string and you did not wrap it with single quote.

To answer your question directly,

```
"SELECT id_test FROM test WHERE name='" + test_name_string + "'"
```

this is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Values must be parameterized.

- [NpgsqlCommand Class](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.html)
- [Examples](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/exampleprograms.html)

Comment: Yeah this is just the answer I came up with myself after a few seconds since I posted the code. I know the must be parameterized but this one line was just for a quick check.